# Fetch last inserted record in entire Mongo database

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-mongo, spring-mongodb

I am using spring mongo data connector and i have some 40 collections in my database. I want to fetch the last inserted record in entire database and not just specific to a collection.

Comment: I don't think you can with a query. Maybe, using a new collection with only one object : each time you insert an object in your 40 collections, you reset this new collection with the last inserted item.

Comment: I'd endorse Odonno's proposal. Sounds like a weird requirement, though. If you run a single application instance you might save it there.